# How can I perpetually retry an IO until I get a result?

Tags: haskell, functional-programming

I'm trying to read an integer from a command line prompt and I want my program keep asking for input until it can parse a proper value.

This is what I came up with

```hs
import Control.Exception
import System.IO

prompt :: String -> IO String
prompt text = do
  putStr text
  hFlush stdout
  getLine

getInt :: IO Int
getInt = handle recoverError readParse
  where recoverError :: SomeException -> IO Int
        recoverError _ = getInt
        readParse = fmap read $ prompt ">> "

main :: IO ()
main = fmap show getInt >>= putStrLn
```

I expected the `handle` function to recursively call `getInt` any time an `Exception` from `read` arises, but apparently that's not the case.

This is what I see when I execute this program

```
$ ./main
>> 10
10

$ ./main
>> not a number
main: Prelude.read: no parse
```

I'm new to haskell so probably missing something obvious here.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `readIO` instead of `read`, as in:

```
readParse = prompt ">> " >>= readIO
```

The difference is that `fmap read` creates an IO action that always succeeds and produces a pure result with an exception embedded in it, while `readIO` creates an IO action that may throw an IO exception but whose pure value result always succeeds. You may also combine `getLine` and `readIO`, using `readLn` instead, as in:

```
prompt :: Read a => String -> IO a
prompt text = do
  ...
  readLn
```

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that the exception from `read` does not arise from `readParse` due to Haskell's laziness. The `read` result is not evaluated until the `show`n string is output by `putStrLn`, and only then the exception happens.

You could probably work around this by using [`evaluate`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.14.0.0/docs/Control-Exception.html#v:evaluate), but the proper solution here is not to rely on exceptions at all:

> [`read`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.14.0.0/docs/Text-Read.html#v:read)
>   fails with an
>   [`error`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.14.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:error)
>   if the parse is unsuccessful, and it is therefore discouraged from
>   being used in real applications. Use
>   [`readMaybe`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.14.0.0/docs/Text-Read.html#v:readMaybe)
>   or
>   [`readEither`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.14.0.0/docs/Text-Read.html#v:readEither)
>   for safe alternatives.

```
getInt :: IO Int
getInt = maybe getInt return =<< readMaybe <$> prompt ">> "
-- alternatively written as
getInt = do
  input <- prompt ">> "
  case readMaybe input of
    Just v  -> return v
    Nothing -> getInt
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I got the difference between `read` and `readMaybe` now, but I'm struggling to understand your example. Can you add some parenthesis to make precedence a bit clearer?

Comment: @L.Catallo `GHCi> :i =<<` => `infixr 1 =<<`, `GHCi> :i <$>` => `infixl 4 <$>`, so the `<$>` operator binds stronger (4) than `=<<` (1), so it's read as `(maybe getInt return) =<< (readMaybe <$> (prompt ">> "))` (the "whitespace" i.e. function application binds the strongest).

Comment: @L.Catallo `=<<` and `<$>` are ways of writing different kinds of "imperative" function application. Think of it like `let f = maybe getInt return in f(readMaybe(prompt(">> "))`.